# using tidyr function separate on a column

Tags: r

I am using the separate function on a column of a data frame see code below:

```
   separate(shootings, Location, into=c("State, City"),sep=",")
```

I am getting a "Too many values at 83 locations" error.

The Location column currently looks like "Milwaukee, Wisconsin"

Any Idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: `into=c("State, City")` should be `into=c("State", "City")`

Comment: Im dumb sorry i will delete this thanks